# How to set section titles centered, bold and underlined?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, document-classes

I'm editing a custom documentclass `.cls` file and would like to set section titles centered, bold and underlined.

```
\def\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
  {\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
  {\centering\bfseries\underbar}}
```

However, `\centering` and `\underbar` does not appear to be compatible. 
With `\underbar`, section titles are underlined but not centered; without `\underbar`, section titles are centered but not underlined.

How to set section titles centered, bold and underlined? I've never edited a documentclass before and the solution may be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\underbar` is not a switch, like centering, and it takes an argument, so you cannot use it the way you're trying to.

The first option is to mess with LaTeX's `\@sect`, which is probably more cumbersome than it's worth.

I think your best shot it `titlesec` with the `explicit` option:

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat\section[block]%
  {\bfseries\centering}
  {\thesection}
  {\baselineskip}
  {\underbar{#1}}
```

but as dexteritas pointed out in the comments, this will fail miserably for long section titles that require a line break. `\underbar` typesets its argument in an `\hbox`, therefore the linebreak doesn't happen. So for long section titles `\underbar` cannot be used.

An alternative that can handle line breaks is the `\ul` command from the `soul` package:

```
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat\section[block]%
  {\bfseries\centering}
  {\thesection}
  {\baselineskip}
  {\ul{#1}}
```

Comment: There is a problem with: `\section{A very long title, witch is longer than one line and therefore needs a linebreak}`.

Comment: @dexteritas Indeed. Thanks! I added a solution that handles line breaks :)